# Chain Rule - What have I done wrong?

Tags: chain-rule

I'm having trouble with what I have done wrong with the chain rule below.  I have tried to show my working as much as possible for you to better understand my issue here.

So:

Find $dy/dx$ for $y=(x^2-x)^3$

 So power to the front will equal = $3(x^2-x)^2 * (2x-1)$

Where did the $-1$ come from in $2x-1$?

How did they get that?

Thanks!

Comment: Whats the derivative of $(x^2-x)$?  It is $2x-1$.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm confused, why isn't it -1x or - x.

Comment: $\frac d{dx}(x^2-x)=\frac d{dx}(x^2)-\frac{d}{dx}(x)=2x-1$

Comment: Thanks I'm just a bit confused on how the x turns into - 1?

Answer (score 2):

So you are evidently confused in how the derivative of $x^2-x$ is computed.
We know that $\frac{d}{dx}k f(x)=k\frac d{dx}f(x)$ and $\frac d{dx}(f(x)+g(x))=\frac d{dx}f(x)+\frac d{dx}g(x)$. 
 So 
$$\frac d{dx}(x^2-x)=\frac d{dx}x^2+\frac d{dx}(-x)=2x+(-1)\frac d{dx}(x)=2x+(-1)1=2x-1$$

Comment: Aditya , Have you viewed @lulu 's profile? pagla gyi h!

Answer (score 1):

Since $(x^n)' = n x^{n-1}$, we have $(x^2)' = 2x$ and $x' = 1$, therefore $(x^2 -x)' = 2x-1$ - differentiation of functions is additive.

Answer (score 0):

Lets denote the following:

$y(x) = (x^2-x)^3$

$f(x)=x^2-x$

$g(x)=x^3$

than $y(x)=g(f(x))$
so by the chain rule you get that $y_x = g_x (f(x)) f_x (x)$

thus in your case $y_x = 3f(x)^2f_x(x)=2(x^2-x)^2(2x-1)$